# Why these two ways of interpolations give different results?

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation, syntax

Consider a data file [distr.dat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpgaegfjqtc73q0/distr.dat?dl=0). It is a tabulated grid in the form `x1,x2, func[x1,x2]`. I interpolate it in two different ways:

```
distrdata = 
  Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "distr.dat"}], "Table"];
x1minmax = MinMax[distrdata[[All, 1]]]
x2minmax = MinMax[distrdata[[All, 2]]]
int1[x1_, x2_] = 
  10^(Interpolation[{Log10[#[[1]]], Log10[#[[2]]], 
         Log10[#[[3]] + 10^-90]} & /@ distrdata, 
      InterpolationOrder -> 1][Log10[x1], Log10[x2]]);
int2[x1_, x2_] = 
  Interpolation[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]} & /@ distrdata, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1][x1, x2];
```

The interpolations are expected to differ in the domains where the function changes quickly - for large values of `x1`, `x2`.

Next, I want to compare the integrals

```
NIntegrate[
 int1[x1, x2], {x1, x1minmax[[1]], x1minmax[[2]]}, {x2, x2minmax[[1]],
   x2minmax[[2]]}, Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"]
NIntegrate[
 int2[x1, x2], {x1, x1minmax[[1]], x1minmax[[2]]}, {x2, x2minmax[[1]],
   x2minmax[[2]]}, Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"]
```

I get two completely different results:

> 0.838699
>
> 7.06604*10^-6

Next, if I take into account that the `int1`, `int2` quickly drop for `x1` > 0.2, I get

```
NIntegrate[
 int1[x1, x2], {x1, x1minmax[[1]], 0.2}, {x2, x2minmax[[1]],
   x2minmax[[2]]}, Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"]
NIntegrate[
 int2[x1, x2], {x1, x1minmax[[1]], 0.2}, {x2, x2minmax[[1]],
   x2minmax[[2]]}, Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"]
```

> 0.83866
>
> 1.04657

Questions:

1. If integrating `int2` over all domain of the definition of `x1` (i.e., from `x1minmax[[1]]` to `x1minmax[[2]]`), what is the reason for the method `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` to behave like `"MonteCarlo"`, i.e., return small results if the integrand is non-zero only within some narrow domain?
2. Can the difference between the values of the integrals when integrating over `x1` up to `0.2` be attributed solely to the way of the interpolation, i.e., adjusting the value of the functions between the data points?

To me, the answer to question 2 is not obvious. Indeed, let us integrate over `x2` only and look at the `x1` integrand:

```
tabb = ParallelTable[{10^x1, 
    Quiet[NIntegrate[
      int1[10^x1, x2], {x2, x2minmax[[1]], x2minmax[[2]]}, 
      Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"]], 
    Quiet[NIntegrate[
      int2[10^x1, x2], {x2, x2minmax[[1]], x2minmax[[2]]}, 
      Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"]]}, {x1, 
    Log10[x1minmax[[1]]], Log10[0.2], 0.1}];
ListLogLogPlot[{{#[[1]], #[[2]]/#[[3]]} & /@ tabb}, Joined -> True, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
```

The ratio of the integrals of `int1`, `int2` departs from 1 everywhere and does not jump except for the domain where the function quickly drops, which I find strange.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I doubt very much about the sense of your attempt "interpolate a distribution".

With a little help `NIntegrate` evaluates similar results. You only have to extend the integration range.

Therfore I assume that integrand takes significant values in the range `x1<.04`and `20<x2<100`

```
NIntegrate[int1[x1, x2], {x1, x1minmax[[1]], 0.04, x1minmax[[2]]}
,{x2,x2minmax[[1]], 20, 100, x2minmax[[2]]} , PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 6, Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"  ]
(*0.838117*)

NIntegrate[int2[x1, x2], {x1, x1minmax[[1]], .04, x1minmax[[2]]}
, {x2,x2minmax[[1]], 20, 100, x2minmax[[2]]} , PrecisionGoal -> 3,AccuracyGoal -> 6, Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision" ]
(*1.04585*)
```

Comment: Thanks! But what do you mean by having doubts?

Comment: A *distribution*  isn't plotable nor interpolable, though let's call your function narrow banded or something like that..